# Git not finding changes in tracked files

Tags: macos, git

I have a very odd problem: git has suddenly stopped being able to detect that I've modified files. I can go into a repository's folder, change a tracked file, and `git status` will say:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

This is especially strange because it took effect gradually. First git-gui stopped being able to notice file changes, but the command line continued to work. Then I restarted the machine and now neither the gui nor the command line can spot changed files.

My best guess is that something is wrong with my PATH. That would explain restarting the machine making it worse, and how the command line could have continued functioning for longer (it was started when the PATH was correct). Coworkers sometimes use my machine, so they may have installed something that modified the path.

In case it's relevant, here's my PATH:

```
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
:/usr/local/git/bin
```

The machine in question is a mac mini. Note that xcode can still detect the changes, and perform commits. But that will only get me so far, until I need some command line specific feature.

I'm unsure how to proceed. How do I diagnose what's wrong? If the problem is PATH, then what do I reorder/remove/add? Secondarily, how do I figure out what broke things in the first place?

Comment: Only my guess, Try `git config --global core.trustctime false`. If this option is  false, the ctime differences between the index and the working tree are ignored.

Comment: @pktangyue Tried setting core.trustctime to false. Has no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my coworker made another clone of the repository. I thought I was modifying files in the original repo, when I modified them in xcode, but actually I was modifying them in the cloned repo.

git status worked in the command line, temporarily, because that command line instance was left by my coworker and pointed to the correct directory. Terminal only shows the name of the current directory, and I had no idea it was nested within the wrong directory. git-gui 'broke first' because my co-worker didn't use git-gui, and so didn't point it at the clone.

So, just a dumb mistake on our part. git was working properly.

Comment: well that happens... but shouldn't using a multi user os ;)